# MongoDB secondary replica permanently in not reachable/healthy state

Tags: mongodb

I have a standard 3 node MongoDB replica set:

- `10.0.2.35` - Primary
- `10.0.3.169` - Secondary
- `10.0.1.48` - Secondary

I'm currently not able to connect to them as a replica set, I can only connect through the primary. If I run `rs.status()` on the primary, I repeatedly get:

```
{
        "set" : "ecReplica",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:10.014Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(-1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "ip-10-0-3-169:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 10717677,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1524510722, 15),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:02Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:08.186Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:09.656Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
                        "syncingTo" : "ip-10-0-2-35:27017",
                        "configVersion" : 405240
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "ip-10-0-1-48:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 6,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:09.116Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:08.404Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "authenticated" : false,
                        "configVersion" : -1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "ip-10-0-2-35:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 10717680,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1524510722, 15),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T19:12:02Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1524486537, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T12:28:57Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 405240,
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

When I ssh into the primary, I see the following error in `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`:

> 2018-04-23T19:23:54.326+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Error in heartbeat request to ip-10-0-1-48:27017; Unauthorized not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetHeartbeat: "ecReplica", pv: 1, v: 405240, from: "ip-10-0-2-35:27017", fromId: 2, checkEmpty: false }

### Additional info

#### Connectivity

I **can** connect to all 3 nodes individually using Mongo Shell and Robo3T using SSH tunneling, but I can't connect to the 3 as a replica set.

Production servers apparently connects successfully to the replica set.

#### telnet

`telnet 10.0.1.48 27017` from `10.0.2.35` works.

#### /etc/mongod.conf

The config files are almost exactly equal, the only difference is in the `net` section:

Node `10.0.1.48`:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,10.0.3.169,10.0.2.35]
```

Node `10.0.3.169`:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [10.0.1.48,10.0.2.35,127.0.0.1]
```

Node `10.0.2.35`:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,10.0.3.169,10.0.1.48]
```

**NOTICE:** the `security` section is empty, so this is not a key-file issue.

#### db.version()

```
3.2.0
```

#### Infrastructure

All nodes are running in the same AWS VPC, while they're in different Availability Zones, they belong to the same Security Group and use the same Network ACLs and Route Tables.

---

This is an inherited setup, it has been live for more than 2 years.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want a replica set connection (with member discovery and failover) as opposed to a direct connection to a single member of a replica set, your remote client needs to be able to connect to the replica set using the host names and ports as configured in `rs.conf()`. Since `ssh` tunnelling works I suspect you are trying to connect via forwarded ports. Can you confirm how your remote client is connecting to the replica set?

Comment: NOTE: the `bindIp` values determine which network interfaces a `mongod` listens to. I notice you have some overlap in your IPs, which is likely incorrect (two members shouldn't have the same IP and port).

Comment: Hi @Stennie... Yes, I'm trying to do it through forwarded ports. I installed mongo shell on the bastion server to test connectivity and it worked as expected, using the following connection string: `mongodb://<user>:<password>@10.0.1.48:27017,10.0.3.169:27017,10.0.2.35:27017/<db-name>?replicaSet=<rs-name>`

Comment: When tuneling, I forward each of the `host:ports` pairs to `9005`, `9006` and `9007` and try to connect to them as `localhost`.

Comment: About your note, I'm not sure what you meant. Each of the individual nodes allows connections from themselves and the other 2 nodes.

Comment: There are several aspects to your question. Port forwarding replica set connections will not work as expected because [Clients use the hostnames listed in the replica set config, not the seed list](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#id119). After connecting to a member of the provided seed list, clients are expected to discover the current replica set configuration (as per `rs.conf()`) and use those canonical hostnames and ports.

Comment: The `bindIP` values are incorrect because this configuration is for specifying the network interfaces a server *listens* to, not the address of remote clients that need to connect. For example, the expected list for `10.0.1.48` is `[127.0.0.1,10.0.1.48]`. Newer versions of MongoDB will warn about this misconfiguration.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why this configuration isn't more problematic given the `bindIP` values unless the configuration files aren't actually being used. Did you recently upgrade or change anything in the configuration? I would also strongly recommend upgrading from 3.2.0 to the latest 3.2.x release (currently 3.2.19) as there have been several years of improvements since the initial release. Minor releases within the same production series only contain bug fixes and security updates (no backward breaking changes).

Comment: Thank's a lot, @Stennie... I ended up figuring that out myself after reading through the docs. I also noticed that the problematic node had `authorization: enabled` uncommented.

I'll update the issue with the current configs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your settings is still `auth` disabled in ReplicaSet.

To enable it, simply add a `security.keyFile` in settings or use `--keyFile` in command line option.

Here is an example showing how to generate such file:

```
openssl rand -base64 756 > <path-to-keyfile>
chmod 400 <path-to-keyfile>
```

then add to `mongod.conf` the path of the genreated keyfile:

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
   keyFile: /path/to/keyfile
```

restart the mongod service, right now your mongo should be `auth` enabled.

for more information about `keyFile`, refer to  [Enforce Keyfile Access Control in a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the root of the problem thanks to the inputs from @Stennie.

I've changed the replica set configuration to use the actual IP addresses instead of the AWS internal DNS.

Also, I fixed the `bindIp` option for the hosts:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,**INSTANCE PRIVATE IP**]


#processManagement:

#security:
#  authorization: enabled

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: ecReplica
#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Still, running `rs.status()` gave me:

```
{
    "set" : "ecReplica",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:03:27.277Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.0.3.169:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 6153,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1524671340, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T15:49:00Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1524672170, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:02:50Z"),
            "configVersion" : 405245,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.0.1.48:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 6,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:03:26.532Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:03:25.651Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "authenticated" : false,
            "configVersion" : -1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.0.2.35:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 5916,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1524671340, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T15:49:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:03:26.531Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:03:25.760Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "configVersion" : 405245
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Also, I noticed that the following line was uncommented in `/etc/mongod.conf` at `10.0.1.48`:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

In the other 2 config files, such line was commented.

When I commented out the `authorization` line and restarted the service, the rogue node could finally sync'ing:

```
{
    "set" : "ecReplica",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:14:18.489Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(-1),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.0.3.169:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 70,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1524672835, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:13:55Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:14:18.248Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:14:16.605Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(1),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing from: 10.0.2.35:27017",
            "syncingTo" : "10.0.2.35:27017",
            "configVersion" : 405245
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "10.0.1.48:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 186,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1524672835, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:13:55Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:14:18.313Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:14:17.533Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(3),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "syncing from: 10.0.3.169:27017",
            "syncingTo" : "10.0.3.169:27017",
            "configVersion" : 405245
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "10.0.2.35:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 186,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1524672835, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:13:55Z"),
            "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1524672748, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:12:28Z"),
            "configVersion" : 405245,
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I still need to find a way to enable `authorization` and keep this working... When I figure that out, I'll edit this answer.

Comment: The MongoDB manual has tutorials for [enabling authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). I don't think it's necessary to update the answer with that information: the original problem was incorrect configuration.